# While loop hangs program after valid input is entered?

Tags: c, while-loop, freeze

I have been stuck with this problem on and off since last night and I'm hoping a second fresh pair of eyes will help.

The problem, if an invalid input is entered in the `userIn` function (anything that isn't a number between 1-99) the test printf at the end of the while loop in `main` prints "ERR = 1", the while loops and `userIn` is called again. So far so good, but when a valid input is entered the test printf at the end of the while loop prints "ERR = 0" and then the program hangs. The test printf saying "HELLO" never gets printed.

Any suggestions as to why are most welcome.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void userIn (int *x)
    {
    char b;
    printf("Please enter a new value for Vm: ");
    scanf(" %i",x);
    while (((b=getchar())!='\n')&&(b!=EOF));
    return; 
    }
int main (void)
    {
    int  fd, x, err;
    char *npipe = "/tmp/fms",
         input[3];
    struct stat info;
    printf("\n");

    //get user input
    err = 1;
    while (err)
        {
        userIn(&x);
        if (x > 0 && x < 100) err = 0;
        //else printf("\033[1A\033[K");

        printf("ERR = %i\n",err);//TEST PRINTF
        }
    printf("HELLO");//TEST PRINTF

    //if pipe exists
    if ( (!lstat(npipe,&info)) && (S_ISFIFO(info.st_mode)) )
        {
        sprintf(input,"%i",x);
        //write user input to named pipe created by 'parent.c'
        fd = open(npipe, O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, input, sizeof(input));
        close(fd);
        }
    else printf("\033[0;31mNamed pipe doesn't exist, %i not passed.\n\n\033[0m",x);
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run your code on my system the output looks like this:

```
Please enter a new value for Vm: 101
ERR = 1
Please enter a new value for Vm: 1
ERR = 0
HELLONamed pipe doesn't exist, 1 not passed.
```

That is, the loop exits exactly when you think it should.  Of course, the code then exits immediately because `/tmp/fms` does not exist on my system.

However, if I *create* `/tmp/fms`, then I see:

```
Please enter a new value for Vm: 1
ERR = 0
```

...and no additional output.  This is because the output from the `printf` statement is buffered, and the write to the named pipe is blocking, so the output never gets flushed.  Adding a `\n` to your printf will probably display it as you expect.

Comment: As an aside, either `gdb` or `strace` can be a great tool for figuring out exactly where your code is hanging.

Comment: Your first output was what I was expecting when the program runs on its own. From what you have said, it blocks on writing to the pipe when run on it's own and when fork-exec'd from the parent program. Could this be because I am not removing the pipe properly when the parent program finishes so I am trying to access an old pipe? I am currently using unlink().

Comment: Also will look into `gdb` and `strace`, cheers for pointing them out.

Comment: Scrap the second question, have just been re-reading the man file on pipes, cheers for the pointer in the right direction.

Comment: In case anyone else ever reads this question...my write to the pipe was blocking because I was performing the write and read actions on the pipe separately not simultaneously. Once I removed the `wait()` from the parent program everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to your intuition, the program freezes somewhere *after* the `printf("HELLO");` line. Since you don't have a newline in that printf, `HELLO` gets buffered up and is not flushed to the terminal immediately.

Is there a process reading from the other end of that pipe of yours?

Comment: Yes, when this program is fork-exec'd from the other process. But if the program is run on its own and the pipe doesn't exist the program should still exit gracefully saying the pipe wasn't used as larsks got on his machine